# Compress a list to string with repetition

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iteration

Logic: compress a list into a string where letters that repeat twice in the list repeat a specified number of times in the resulting string.

Examples:

- `['a','a',2,'b','c','c',3]`, --> `aabccc`
- `['a,','a',2]` --> `aa`
- `['c','c',3]` --> `ccc`.

My code is:

```
def run_length_decoder(in_list):
list=[]
for i in range(0,len(in_list)-1):
    if in_list[i]==in_list[i+1]:
        for x in range((i+2)-1):
            list.append(in_list[i])
    else:
        list.append(in_list[i])
list.append(in_list[-1])
word = ""
for letter in list:
    word += str(letter)
return word
```

This doesn't work... because running the above with `['a', 'a', 2, 'b', 'b', 2, 'a', 'b', 'a']` returns `'aaa2bbbbbb2aba'`, but should return `'aabbaba'`.

Comment: `for x in range((i+2)-1):` should be `for x in range(in_list[i + 2]):`

Comment: Are you sure about the encoded list? It feels like a weird way to encode.

Comment: `"".join(["" if isinstance(letter, int) else letter for letter in list])`

Comment: @Avezan, That wouldn't work because `['c', 'c', 3]` should return `'ccc'`.

Comment: @jpp I am out, not understanding logic...

Comment: How should `['a', 'b', 3]` be handled?

Comment: @VPfB, I'm assuming `'abbb'`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems complicated. For starters, you should correct indentation. In addition, since having a numeric counter is optional, you need to add logic to identify integers versus strings. Finally, since the number of letters does not need to be in sync with the following counter you need to attach a letter to each counter explicitly.

One way you can do this is via `itertools.groupby` and a list comprehension.

```
from itertools import groupby, zip_longest

L = ['a', 'a', 2, 'b', 'b', 2, 'a', 'b', 'a']

L2 = [i for i, _ in groupby(L)]

res = ''.join([i*(j if isinstance(j, int) else 1)
               for i, j in zip_longest(L2, L2[1:])
               if isinstance(i, str)])

print(res)

aabbaba
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use unpacking in a `while` loop with `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
def group_data(f):
  def wrapper(_s):
    return list(f([[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(_s, key=lambda x:isinstance(x, str))]))
  return wrapper

@group_data
def decompress(stream): 
  while stream:
    if len(stream) == 1:
       [[_, v]] = stream
       yield v
       stream = []
    else:
       [flag, a], [flag2, b], *_stream = stream
       if flag and not flag2:
         yield a if b[0] ==2 else [a[-1]]*b[0] if len(set(a)) == 1 else [*a[:-1], *([a[-1]]*b[0])]
         stream = _stream
       else:
         yield a
         stream = [[flag, b], *_stream]

data = [['a', 'a', 2, 'b', 'b', 2, 'a', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 3, 'b', 'b', 2, 'a', 'b', 'a', 3]]
new_result = list(map(lambda x:''.join(''.join(i) for i in decompress(x)), data))
```

Output:

```
['aabbaba', 'aaabbabaaa']
```

Answer (score 0):

With a generator function:

```
def repeat(x):
    def _repeat(x):
        it = iter(x)
        last = nxt = next(it)
        yield last
        while it:
            try:
                last = nxt
                nxt = next(it)
            except StopIteration:
                # See PEP 479 / new handling in Python 3.5
                break
            if isinstance(nxt, str):
                yield nxt
            elif isinstance(nxt, int):
                rpt = nxt - 2
                if rpt:
                    yield last * rpt
    return ''.join(_repeat(x))

>>> x = ['a', 'a', 2, 'b', 'c', 'c', 3]
>>> repeat(x)
'aabccc'

>>> y = ['a', 'a', 2, 'b', 'b', 2, 'a', 'b', 'a']
>>> repeat(y)
'aabbaba'

>>> repeat(['c', 'c', 3])
'ccc'
```

The inner function says, "keep advancing/yielding until you hit an `int` *n*."  When that is hit, repeat the previous character seen *n - 2* times.

Explicitly [checking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/) for `StopIteration` is needed as of Python 3.5.